# Homotopy equivalence: $X_1 \times Y_1 \sim X_2 \times Y_2$ if $X_1 \sim X_2$, $Y_1 \sim Y_2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> $X_1, X_2$ are homotopy equivalent, $Y_1, Y_2$ -- too. Prove that $X_1 \times Y_1 \sim X_2 \times Y_2$.

Attempt: $\exists$ continuous $f_X: X_1 \rightarrow X_2, g_X: X_2 \rightarrow X_1, f_X \circ g_X = id _{X_2}, g_X \circ f_X = id_{X_1}; f_Y: Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2, g_Y: Y_2 \rightarrow Y_1, f_Y \circ g_Y = id _{Y_2}, g_Y \circ f_Y = id_{Y_1}$. 
Let $f_{XY}((x_1, y_1)) = (f_X(x_1), f_Y(y_1))$, $g_{XY}((x_2, y_2)) = (g_X(x_2), g_Y(y_2)).$ 
Then we need to prove the continuity of $f_{XY}$ and $g_{XY}$. I have no idea how.

Comment: Maps into a product are continuous iff their compositions with the projections are. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties